# nextjs, etherjs, invalid address or ENS name

Tags: etherjs

I'm using Nextjs.

on sample.jsx

```
  console.log(address)// 0xd56A6DB7d844722627473C07f840c2604E622161

  console.log(typeof(address)) // string

 const ethers = require('ethers')
 let url = "https://sample.net:8293";
 let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
  
    let balance = await provider.getBalance(address)
```

**Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.7.2)**

WHY?

Comment: I am having the same issue!